# Is it possible to skip the next line if 'x' text is entered? C#

Tags: c#

I apologize if this has already been answered else where, I've looked but couldn't find anything. Also this is my first time ever asking a programming related question, I'm really bad with articulating. I'm working on it. Thank you in advanced!

Is it possible to skip the next lines asking for input, to the if statement if input is exit?

```
                        while (isAdding == true)
                    {
                        Console.Write("First Name: ");
                        input = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Last Name: ");
                        input2 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Address: ");
                        input3 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Phone Number: ");
                        input4 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Email Address: ");
                        input5 = Console.ReadLine();



                        if (input == "exit" || input2 == "exit" || input3 == "exit" || input4 == "exit" || input5 == "exit")
                        {
                            isAdding = false;
                            //break;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current syntax, you need to check for the input values on every step.

```
Console.Write("First Name: ");
input = Console.ReadLine();

if(input == "exit"){
   break;
}

Console.Write("Last Name: ");
input2 = Console.ReadLine();

if(input2 == "exit"){
   break;
}
```

If you're purpose is to stop the iteration after all the inputs are saved, then your code is sufficient.

A cleaner way is putting the evaluation inside a function.

```
public bool ShouldExit(string firstName, string lastName){
   if(firstName == "exit" || lastName == "exit"){
      return true
   }
}
```

Then call that function instead.

```
if (ShouldExit(input,input2))
{
   isAdding = false;
   //break;
}
```

Comment: I meant to ask if there was a way to do so without multiple if statements repeated, or if there was a better way of implementing it. Thank you for the swift response!

Comment: @mstrbubbles There's another slightly cleaner way, you could put the evaluation inside a bool function. That's the only way I believe, and it's not that complex as well so your program is fine even if it's repeating. I updated the answer.